(Ubuntu 24.04 fresh upgrade) Failed to retrieve share list from server: Permission Denied
I had Ubuntu 22.04 working just fine, decided to try the upgrade to 24.04.
The upgrade worked with just a few glitches which I am trying to work through. The latest glitch is trying to access my old WD Sentinel DX4000 running Windows Server 2008.
The NAS appears in Nautilus "Other Locations", Networks.
I click it and expect it to provide me a list of shared folders, or ask for a name/password, but instead get this cryptic window:
Unable to access location
Failed to retrieve share list from server:
Permission denied
Share Error: https://postimg.cc/zHRZcQFP
The NAS has 5 shared folders: Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos, and Recorded TV.
My old entry in /etc/fstab for the Documents folder still works:
//192.168.1.10/Documents /mnt/sentinel cifs credentials=/home/grunchy/.smbcredentials,mountvers=2.0,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,x-gvfs-show 0 0

I tried setting up similar shares for the other folders, but no luck.

I think this is because your old router understands only the SMB1 protocol, which is deprecated everywhere because it is unsafe.
Anyway, on 22.04LTS my solution to this is to modify smb.conf in /etc/samba and modify/add the lines "server min protocol = NT1" and "client min protocol = NT1". (=SMB1)
This is a bad work-around as it makes your system less safe, the usual security vs practicality trade-off.
Edit your file with
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
then restart samba with
sudo systemctl restart smbd nmbd
Hope this helps.

Thanks for the tip, sorry, it had no effect.

Ok I was able to mount my "Recorded TV" subfolder by editing /etc/fstab:
//192.168.1.10/Recorded\040TV /mnt/Recorded_TV cifs credentials=/home/grunchy/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,x-gvfs-show 0 0
I went into /etc/samba/smb.conf and commented out:
#client min protocol = NT1
#server min protocol = NT1
name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins
#client max protocol = SMB3
I can access all my NAS devices that are configured in /etc/fstab.
